# Write SqlDataReader to immediate window c#

Tags: c#, sql-server, visual-studio-2013, immediate-window, output-window

I am trying to debug a SQL response which is throwing an error:

> Conversion failed when converting the varchar value '0.01' to data type bit.

That does not make a lot of sense as object does not have any bools.

Code:

```
 using (var connection = _connectionProvider.GetDbConnection())
 {
    connection.Open();
    return connection.Query<Rate>(query, parameters);
 }
```

SQL that gets executed (I manually added parameters):

```
select * from (select top 1 BuildNumber, RateVersion, SampleId, Tariff, TariffStepName, Factor1, Result1 from dbo.Rates
where Tariff = 'Default' and TariffStepName = 'I_P' and (RateVersion <= 1) and Factor1 = 'false' and (SampleId is null)
order by RateVersion desc, sampleId desc) top1
```

I placed breakpoint on where read happens (`connection.Query<Rate>(query, parameters)`), then enabled break on exceptions and when it failed jumped deeper into stack to TdsParser `TryRun()` (couple levels higher where exception is thrown)

> System.Data.dll!System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.TryRun(System.Data.SqlClient.RunBehavior runBehavior, System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand cmdHandler, System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader dataStream, System.Data.SqlClient.BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParserStateObject stateObj, out bool dataReady) + 0x1ce1 bytes

At this point I have access to `dataStream` which is [SqlDataReader](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldatareader(v=vs.110).aspx)

I am looking for a way to output 'raw' result right out of `SqlDataReader`, something like

```
System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine((new System.IO.StreamReader(stream)).ReadToEnd());
```

but for `SqlDataReader`.

**EDIT**

as per request in comment

```
public class Rate
{
    public string Tariff { get; set; }
    public string TariffStepName { get; set; }
    public string Factor1 { get; set; }
    public string Factor2 { get; set; }
    public string Factor3 { get; set; }
    public string Factor4 { get; set; }
    public string Factor5 { get; set; }
    public string Factor6 { get; set; }
    public string Factor7 { get; set; }
    public string Factor8 { get; set; }
    public string Factor9 { get; set; }
    public string Factor10 { get; set; }
    public decimal Result1 { get; set; }
    public decimal Result2 { get; set; }
    public decimal Result3 { get; set; }
    public decimal Result4 { get; set; }
    public decimal Result5 { get; set; }
    public decimal Result6 { get; set; }
    public decimal Result7 { get; set; }
    public decimal Result8 { get; set; }
    public decimal Result9 { get; set; }
    public decimal Result10 { get; set; }
    public string TextResult1 { get; set; }
    public string TextResult2 { get; set; }
    public string TextResult3 { get; set; }
    public string TextResult4 { get; set; }
    public string TextResult5 { get; set; }
    public int? SampleId { get; set; }
    public int BuildNumber { get; set; }
    public decimal? RateVersion { get; set; }
}
```

SQL

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.[Rates](
    [BuildNumber] [int] NOT NULL,
    [Tariff] [varchar](30) NOT NULL,
    [TariffStepName] [varchar](60) NOT NULL,
    [Factor1] [varchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [Factor2] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [Factor3] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [Factor4] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [Factor5] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [Factor6] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [Factor7] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [Factor8] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [Factor9] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [Factor10] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [Result1] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [Result2] [decimal](19, 6) NULL,
    [Result3] [decimal](19, 6) NULL,
    [Result4] [decimal](19, 6) NULL,
    [Result5] [decimal](19, 6) NULL,
    [Result6] [decimal](19, 6) NULL,
    [Result7] [decimal](19, 6) NULL,
    [Result8] [decimal](19, 6) NULL,
    [Result9] [decimal](19, 6) NULL,
    [Result10] [decimal](19, 6) NULL,
    [RateVersion] [decimal](18, 2) NULL,
    [SampleId] [int] NULL,
    [TextResult1] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [TextResult2] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [TextResult3] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [TextResult4] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [TextResult5] [varchar](50) NULL
)
```

**EDIT2:** For those who are wondering what was the cause

statement was actually being converted to this by additional mechanism

```
exec sp_executesql N'select * from (select top 1 BuildNumber, RateVersion, SampleId, Tariff, TariffStepName, Factor1, Result1 from dbo.Rates
where Tariff = @Tariff and TariffStepName = @TariffStepName and (RateVersion <= @RV) and Factor1 = @Factor1 and (SampleId is null)
order by RateVersion desc, sampleId desc) top1 
',N'@Tariff varchar(50),@TariffStepName varchar(50),@RV decimal(3,2),@Factor1 bit',@Tariff='Default',@TariffStepName='I_P',@RV=1.00,@Factor1=0
go
```

this then would fail with error when there was no row by selecting not `top 1` like it was intended but row after that then wouldn't cast to bit

Question still stands: **How do I write SqlDataReader when debugging on the fly to immediate window?**

Comment: Are you using some extensions ? Where does the method `Query<T>` come from ?

Comment: @user3185569 Hi, I am using dapper, but it's using underlying Sql server mechanism.

Comment: Can you show the class `Rate` along with the `CREATE` statement of your  table in SQL. There seems to be a mismatch in the data types.

Comment: One last thing i guess. What does `query` hold ? Can you show your raw SQL Query ? Maybe the error is in the query itself.

Comment: @user3185569 query returns results ok when executed directly (via SQL management studio).

Comment: This is very confusing. One hint i can give you is to start to remove the conditions in the where one by one, to detect which clause is causing the error.

Comment: Your query is perfectly fine. But the error you get i guess is because of actual data in the table. In any of your column some wrong data is entered. Please check your `Rate` table's records if its not too big table. My doubt is on `Factor1` and `Result1` column. But better you check all column

Comment: pretty clear you had `new { ..., Factor1 = false, ... }` instead of `"false"` in the parameters.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**How do I write SqlDataReader when debugging on the fly to immediate window?**

`SqlDataReader` implements the interface [`IDataReader`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.idatareader.aspx).  The following tricks apply to any reader implementing this interface.  As with `(new System.IO.StreamReader(stream)).ReadToEnd()`, these techniques will consume the contents of the data reader, so it will no longer be usable.

**Dumping results purely on the fly.**

If you don't have time to prepare and need to look at your reader's contents right away, you can load your data reader into a `DataTable` defined in the immediate window, them print out the XML for that table.

First, define three run-time global variables in the immediate window by typing:

```
object [] _objs = null;
DataTable _table = null;
DataSet _set = null;
```

Do this once per session.

Next, if the code has already begun to read through the table columns, you can get the values of the current row by typing:

```
_objs = new object[dataStream.FieldCount];
dataStream.GetValues(_objs);
_objs
```

The current values will now be displayed.

Then, to read in and display the remainder of the rows, do the following:

```
_table = new DataTable();
_table.Load(dataStream);
_set = new DataSet();
_set.Tables.Add(_table);
_set.GetXml();
Debug.WriteLine(_set.GetXml());
```

You will see the contents of `_set` printed out in the Immediate Window as an XML string.  Note that if the table is partially read, [`DataTable.Load(IDataReader)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7x8ccbsb(v=vs.110).aspx) will skip the current row, so dump the current values first.

This works well for readers corresponding to a single table, but not for readers corresponding to multiple tables that form a set.

**Dumping results using a small debugging library.**

If you have a little time to prepare or need to debug a multi-table reader, you can do the following.

First, create a small debugging DLL project with utilities such as the following.  *You do not need to link this into the project you are actually debugging.*

```
namespace DataReaderDebugUtilities
{
    public static class DataReaderExtensions
    {
        public static object[] CurrentValues(this IDataReader reader)
        {
            if (reader == null)
                throw new ArgumentNullException();
            var objs = new object[reader.FieldCount];
            reader.GetValues(objs);
            return objs;
        }

        public static KeyValuePair<string, object> [] CurrentNamesAndValues(this IDataReader reader)
        {
            if (reader == null)
                throw new ArgumentNullException();
            var query = Enumerable.Range(0, reader.FieldCount).Select(i => new KeyValuePair<string, object>(reader.GetName(i), reader.GetValue(i)));
            return query.ToArray();
        }

        public static string ToStringAsDataTable(this IDataReader reader)
        {
            if (reader == null)
                throw new ArgumentNullException();
            var sb = new StringBuilder();
            using (var textWriter = new StringWriter(sb))
            using (var jsonWriter = new JsonTextWriter(textWriter) { Formatting = Formatting.Indented })
            {
                var serializer = JsonSerializer.CreateDefault();
                jsonWriter.WriteDataTable(reader, serializer);
            }
            return sb.ToString();
        }

        public static string ToStringAsDataSet(this IDataReader reader)
        {
            if (reader == null)
                throw new ArgumentNullException();
            var sb = new StringBuilder();
            using (var textWriter = new StringWriter(sb))
            using (var jsonWriter = new JsonTextWriter(textWriter) { Formatting = Formatting.Indented })
            {
                var serializer = JsonSerializer.CreateDefault();
                jsonWriter.WriteDataSet(reader, serializer);
            }
            return sb.ToString();
        }
    }

    public static class JsonExtensions
    {
        public static void WriteDataTable(this JsonWriter writer, IDataReader reader, JsonSerializer serializer)
        {
            if (writer == null || reader == null || serializer == null)
                throw new ArgumentNullException();
            writer.WriteStartArray();
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                writer.WriteStartObject();
                for (int i = 0; i < reader.FieldCount; i++)
                {
                    writer.WritePropertyName(reader.GetName(i));
                    serializer.Serialize(writer, reader[i]);
                }
                writer.WriteEndObject();
            }
            writer.WriteEndArray();
        }

        public static void WriteDataSet(this JsonWriter writer, IDataReader reader, JsonSerializer serializer)
        {
            if (writer == null || reader == null || serializer == null)
                throw new ArgumentNullException();
            writer.WriteStartObject();

            do
            {
                var tableName = string.Empty;
                var schemaTable = reader.GetSchemaTable();
                if (schemaTable != null)
                    tableName = schemaTable.Rows.Cast<DataRow>()
                        .Select(r => r[schemaTable.Columns[System.Data.Common.SchemaTableColumn.BaseTableName]].ToString())
                        .FirstOrDefault();
                writer.WritePropertyName(tableName ?? string.Empty);
                writer.WriteDataTable(reader, serializer);
            }
            while (reader.NextResult());

            writer.WriteEndObject();
        }
    }
}
```

(Note - the code to get the table name is not fully tested.)

Note I am using [json.net](/questions/tagged/json.net) to serialize result values and format the overall results.  You could use a different serializer if you prefer.

Build the project in debug mode and copy it to a convenient location, say `C:\Temp\DataReaderDebugUtilities.dll`.

Next, when you need to dump the values inside a data reader, in the immediate window, type:

```
Assembly.LoadFile(@"C:\Temp\DataReaderDebugUtilities.dll");
```

Now you can call methods from this DLL in the immediate window even though it is not linked into your project.  Thus typing:

```
DataReaderDebugUtilities.DataReaderExtensions.CurrentNamesAndValues(dataStream)
```

will show you the names and values of the current row, if any.

Then typing

```
string _s = DataReaderDebugUtilities.DataReaderExtensions.ToStringAsDataSet(dataStream);
```

or

```
string _s = DataReaderDebugUtilities.DataReaderExtensions.ToStringAsDataTable(dataStream);
```

will dump the remaining contents of the reader as a data table or data set into a JSON string for manual inspection.

Answer (score 0):

- You could set a breakpoint inside Dapper code - is Open Source.
- Result1 is defined as varchar(50), but your C# class says decimal.

Comment: Nice spot, this means there has to be mechanism for conversion somewhere, as when I changed Result1 to string in C# it gave 100s of errors, even better when I checked select `SELECT distinct cast([Result1] as decimal(18,10))
  FROM dbo.[Rates]` it didn't give me any errors. At this point I will go to speak to team on who wrote it like this (and why) and what is going on with this....

Answer (score 0):

`Conversion failed when converting the varchar value '0.01' to data type bit.` 
i think the message is thrown by SQL server. so there should be error at SQL level. Try checking actual query in SQL profiler and run in SSMS.

Comment: do you mean if you copy paste query from profiler to SSMS and run then it runs fine? I suspect issue in query, because this message comes at SQL level (for ex: `select convert(bit,'0.01')`)